# Language stored in Useprofile.language field applied on user log in

Tags: django, session, internationalization, authentication

I need to set language for user in 2 cases:

1. User logs in (django checks his UserProfile field for language field value and sets the proper lang)
2. Users chenges lang in "user preferences" page.

I've tried with "user_logged_in" signal receiver

```
from django.utils import translation
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def setlang(sender, **kwargs):
    translation.activate(kwargs['user'].get_profile().language)
    kwargs['request'].session['django_language'] = translation.get_language()
```

This works fine until I restart my django instance. Though session is alive (no need to log in again) website is being displayed in language specified in settings.LANGUAGE

I think the same applies to situation #2 (on user preferences form save())

Answer (score 3):

Following up to Timmy's answer you can find an already published middleware that does the job for you!

The translation of a Django app with the preferred language selected by a registered user can be done with the middleware [django-user-language-middleware](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-user-language-middleware/). This allows easy translation of your Django app by looking at the selected language in the `user.language` field.

Usage:

1. Add a language field to your user model:

   ```
   class User(auth_base.AbstractBaseUser, auth.PermissionsMixin):
       # ...
       language = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                                   choices=settings.LANGUAGES,
                                   default=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
   ```
2. Install the middleware from pip:

   `pip install django-user-language-middleware`
3. Add it to your middleware class list in settings to listen to requests:

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE = [  # Or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10
       ...
       'user_language_middleware.UserLanguageMiddleware',
       ...
   ]
   ```

I hope this may help people landing on this question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better if [you use middleware to achieve this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/). Django provides a way to add in hooks at various places throughout a request so that you can add custom code.

In your case: check on every request if there is a language variable in the session, if not, fetch the users language preference from the database and save it to the session variable. Check on a save signal whether or not the user has changed their preference; if so, update the session variable (you might have problems getting access to the request from the model level so it might be better to do this in the view).

Comment: Yeah... looks like middleware is the only way to go.. but why isn't the language read from session? settings.LANGUAGE is the last one in django "search for lang" priority list. Thanks

Comment: FIXED: 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware' was disabled... now it works without translation.activate()

Answer (score 0):

I've used this snippet, but it conflicts with the Regular LocaleMiddleware, and thus I can't add a multilingual content farm.
http://django-hotclub.googlecode.com/svn-history/r708/trunk/pinax/profiles/middleware.py